# Menu button not working on the emulator in a Maps Application

Tags: android, android-emulator

when i am trying to run the example of Maps as in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html , the menu button doesn't seem to work. I tried the default Maps app in the emulator and there it was working. 
Also i intend to add an item when a user presses that button , how can do it?

Answer (score 1):

That is the Example of Mapview not for a Menus. Look out this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html). It had the answer of all your Questions.